# How do you show the desktop in a blink in Ubuntu?

Tags: shortcut-keys

We know you can either click on the show desktop icon or use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to ask Ubuntu to show the desktop. Unfortunately, this does not always show the desktop in one action.

Sometime, and this is true for at least the last 4 version of the OS, it brings up first to the front all the windows, THEN, with a second click, show you the desktop.

This is very annoying, as when you show the desktop it generally to quickly click on a shortcut.

To understand what I'm talking about, open 7 windows, minimize some, bring some to the front, maximize one, then show the desktop. Then do that on Windows. You'll see the difference.

Comment: If the show desktop is not working correctly for you, then you need to file a bug report.  FYI, following the steps you describe above on Maverick alpha, the desktop is show almost instantaneously, without fail.

Comment: This is unreproducible.

Comment: This problem arise even on a live CD. It's MY problem. Should I make video out of it to show what's wrong and how to reproduce it ?

Comment: It is perfectly reproducible. Just open a bunch of windows, minimize some and have one maximized. If you then try to show the desktop, it first unminimizes all Windows, and then if you click again, it'll minimize them.

Comment: I think this only happens if you press the show desktop button and then open new windows. This is not a bug but intended behavior: Look at the tooltip of the button, after you press it it changes to something like "restore windows".

Comment: Oh, correcting myself: It may indeed be a bug, see my answer :-)

Comment: Why minimize everything? Use `ctrl+alt+left/right` to switch to a new desktop :)

Comment: @keyboardmonkey: lol, it's true. Thinking about it, I may do that in the future. It has one BIG drawback though, if you open a windows related to your current task, it is on the other desktop. Then, either you move it or have to remember it here.

Comment: Why is it downvoted while it's clearly an ubuntu bug ?

Comment: Also reproducible with SUPER+D on Natty

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There seems to be a problem when compiz ("desktop effects") is enabled:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-panel/+bug/236376

I'm afraid for now the only workaround is to disable all desktop effects.

Comment: Indeed, tested and that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

On my system I use compiz to show desktop. I install simple compizconfig and open the last tab called "edges", I choose one edge and tell it to show my desktop. So when I move the mouse to that edge, it either hide all apps (screenlets included) or show them all.

Comment: Yes, but it does exactly the same thing with the same problem. -1

Answer (score -1):

if u r using gnome-shell i installed a gnome-shell extension comes with a icon on the panel toggles shows desktop :

use this link to install : https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/64/show-desktop-button/